# Audit Log Executor Is Incorrect

Tags: discord.js

This bot I am making is tasked with logging when a user receives a role and when a user has a role removed. It prints that to a desired channel. Additionally I want the bot to send data to a database for the user when they receive a certain role. This part is working. I want the code to IGNORE the database addition/removal when the bot is the one adding or removing roles. This part is not working correctly. The way I have it setup is to check the audit logs to see who the executor of the action was. The intended effect is that if the executor's username matches my bot's username, the code does not run. However, even when the bot adds or removes a user's role, and the audit log visibly shows the bot as the one completing the action, when logging the entry to the console it displays myself, not the bot, as the executor.

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async function(oldMember, newMember){ //When a user has their roles changed (added or removed)

const entry = await oldMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: 'MEMBER_UPDATE'}).then(audit => audit.entries.first()) //Find audit logs pertaining to member update

console.log(entry) //Print the data to the console

if (entry.executor.username == "PolarBot") { //If the executor of the role addition is the bot then do nothing
    return;
}
else { //Otherwise execute the code
    if (oldMember.author == client.user) { // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
        return
    }
     if (oldMember.roles.size < newMember.roles.size) { //If the old member has less roles than the new member
         currency.add(oldMember.user.id, 1); //Establish user in the database
         const target = oldMember.user.id //Establish target ID for the database

         for (const role of newMember.roles.map(x => x.id)) { //Find the new role

        const item =  await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role).name}` } } }); //Set item to be the role added
        const user =  await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: target } }); //Find the target location in the database and name it user

        const items = await user.getItems(); //Ignore this
        user.addItem(item); //Add role to the database for that uesr


            if (!oldMember.roles.has(role)) { //Check to see if the old member does not have the role
                oldMember.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "change-logging").send({embed: { //Send log message to the correct channel
        color: 16723502,
        title: "**User Roles Updated:**",
        description: oldMember.user.tag,

        fields: [
      {
        name: "**New Role(s)**",
        value: `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role).name}`,
        inline: true
      }
    ],

    timestamp: new Date(),
    }})  

            }


         }

    }

    if (oldMember.roles.size > newMember.roles.size) {

        currency.add(oldMember.user.id, 1);  
        const target = oldMember.user.id    
         for (const role of oldMember.roles.map(x => x.id)) {

        const item =  await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role).name}` } } });
        const user =  await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: target } });

        const items = await user.getItems();
        user.removeItem(item); //Subtract role from the data base


            if (!newMember.roles.has(role)) {
        oldMember.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "change-logging").send({embed: {
        color: 16723502,
        title: "**User Roles Updated:**",
        description: oldMember.user.tag,

        fields: [
      {
        name: "**Removed Role(s)**",
        value: `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role).name}`,
        inline: true
      }
    ],

    timestamp: new Date(),
    }})  

            }


        }
    }



}
    });
```

Expected Result: When logging "entry" to the console the executor section should read my bot's username.
Actual Result: I am listed as the executor.

Link to console output:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the `user` property of the `options` parameter in [`Guild.fetchAuditLogs`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs)? For example, only fetch the *first* log of the *user* updating, like `...fetchAuditLogs({ type: 'MEMBER_UPDATE', user: newMember.user, limit: 1 })`.

Comment: I’ll try it and let you know, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I’m a bit silly and the actual audit log event I wanted to call was MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE not MEMBER_UPDATE